# SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby, drop-table

How to disable(I don't know the correct term yet) foreign keys before **DROP TABLE**?
OR

correct way to drop a table?

followed steps provided [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-drop-table/)

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E724S.png)

got the same error again **SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE users**.

```
(byebug) execute "PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF"
-- execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")
   -> 0.0009s
[]
(byebug) execute "DROP TABLE users"
-- execute("DROP TABLE users")
*** ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey Exception: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE users

nil
```

Comment: @robinEPtion do you want to remove/delete/drop table or foreign key?

Comment: @AayQue drop table

Comment: @robincEPtion are you drooping table using migrations?

Comment: @robincEption than you need to first remove the values of this Table which are stored as foreign keys in another table(s).

Comment: yes @Gabbar,  I am supposed to do it during the migration.

Comment: @robincEPtion can you share you user model code?

Comment: The user table has one self reference and referenced by another table.
Now What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose your users is associated with posts table then create a migration and remove

```
class RemoveForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # remove the old foreign_key
    remove_foreign_key :posts, :users
  end
end
```